# Receiving a json from an API on Flutter app

Tags: android, api, flutter

I'm trying to receive the response on a http post but the response comes empty. I know its something basic but i can't make it work.
It should receive a JSON with some data, but the data doesn't come, probably its a problem on the reply part on my code.

Heres the code:

```
  Future<void> _login2() async {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.badCertificateCallback =
        ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);

    String url = 'https://sistema.hutransportes.com.br/api/login.php';

    Map map = {"user": "test", "pass": "123456"};
    HttpClientRequest request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
    request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(map)));
    HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
    String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
    print(reply); //should show the data from the http

  }
```

Comment: What does it print?

Comment: Nothing, it comes empty.

Comment: It's really strange. I tried on dartpad and to me, it seems like the HttpClient client = new HttpClient() is the place where it gets stuck. When I declared HttpClient globally, the app failed to start so it probably is a bug and explains why your code never reaches the print statement. Try to print something above the client declaration, it worked for me but when I print something immediately below, it doesn't. I suggest you use some different library. Try using this one https://pub.dev/packages/http

Comment: I tried to write normal dart code outside flutter and the results are the same. It's probably some bug with HttpClient

Comment: Using the http package it works normally, but i can't use it because i have a problem with the https certificate and only with the httpclient i got a way to avoid the certificate verification

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to use the powerful library [https://pub.dev/packages/dio](http://DIO)

Comment: Do you know if I can ignore the https certificate errors on dio? The "client.badCertificateCallback" part in my code.

Comment: I am not sure, but you can see https://pub.dev/packages/dio_http2_adapter